# problem with flutter and gradle :Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gr

Tags: java, flutter, gradle, ssl-certificate, build.gradle

I have been developing an app using flutter and everything was going well until I upgraded flutter to use a certain package. I have had errors since then even after downgrading to the ancient version of flutter.

Here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1900)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Here's my build.gradle file:

```
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url  "https://dl.bintray.com/alphacep/vosk"
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url  "https://dl.bintray.com/alphacep/vosk"
            }
        }
    }

    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
```

Here's the graddle-wrapper.properties :

```
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

And finally the flutter doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H15 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.22.6 at /Users/fern7hl4/Library/flutter
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (3 months ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/fern7hl4/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin installed
    • Dart plugin version 201.9335
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.54.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.20.0

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

I get approximately the same error when I replace http with https in http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip and I tried with different versions of flutter and gradle and nothing seems to work.

I really hope someone knows what's happening here and could give me a hand to solve this problem.

Comment: This is happening because wrapper is not able to download the gradle 5.1.1 . But 403 is used to refuse to connection. Try upgrading your gradle 6.83. and your gradle plugin too

Comment: and make it https and not http. This is the location from where zips are downloaded https://services.gradle.org/distributions/. and its https

Comment: Thanks for answering. Here's the error I got when I modified 
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.3-all.zip :

 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)

And more,it doesn't fit in the comment

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a network problem. Do you try disabling the firewall?
Try to download this file, this is the file that Gradle cannot access.
http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

Comment: Thanks for answering. Where do you think I should refer to the file after downloading it ?